MDT Task sequence log
I have a Windows 2016 Server running WDS to install Windows Images. There were some Boot images running in the Windows deployment boot images. I currently have one activated. In the Deployment Workbench there were a couple Deployment Shares created. I currently have one, but am not sure how to tell which is tied to the Boot image.
I am trying to add a batch file in a task sequence, but have no clue if it is actually running or not. The task is to install some certificates, but they are not being installed and I'm trying to figure out why it is failing and where it failed.
How can I tell or update the Boot image wim file which deployment share task sequence events it is pulling?
